# Where Spring Roo's installed addon is stored on machine hard drive?

Tags: location, spring-roo, add-on

As in Spring Roo's [guide on DBRE](http://docs.spring.io/spring-roo/reference/html/base-dbre.html), we need to install `jdbc driver` for MySQL.

> roo> addon install id --searchResultId 01

My question is where the downloaded addon location on the hard drive; as we know the location, we can copy it for later use to save the long downloading time.

Answer (score 1):

It is installed in `$ROO_HOME/cache`

Comment: Thank you @eriuz. I'll check and back to accept your answer as it works.